# Правильное написание слова "свежемороженый"

Tags: орфография

Как пишется слово "свежемороженый"?

Answer (score 1):

Это **отглагольное прилагательное**, потому что образовано от глагола несовершенного вида "*морозить*".
Если нет зависимого слова, например,

> Я купил свежемороженую рыбу

тогда в нём пишется одно Н.
Если есть - по правилу должно быть два (НН), но (тут уже я додумываю), как мне кажется, найти фразу типа

> СвежеморожеННая вчера рыба

-- это что-то нереальное.

> МорожеННая десять раз рыба

мне кажется можно сказать, но это уже другое слово.

Answer (score 0):

Слово пишется слитно. Тут сложные слова соеденены между собой соединительной буквой **е**, поэтому пишутся слитно.

Answer (score 0):

Слитно, потому что это сложное слово, образованное из подчинительного словосочетания: "морозить свежей".